# Startup of stm32f100rbtx

Tags: c++, eclipse, stm32, openocd

I found problem with  running program  on STM32F100RBTx. I am using eclipse + zadig + openOCD. Everything was working fine until I tried to handle some interrupts.

Looking through google I think that the problem is in startup file and with assembler file. I looked for proper files but without any success. Could anyone help me to repair that file or look for another one ?

[Link to assembler file](http://pastebin.com/EtYUTazT)

[Link to startup.s](http://pastebin.com/bT2ah445)

pastebin . com/WSrXr2Yi -- vectors.c (have no reputation)

My main:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "MYGPIO.h"

typedef My_GPIO<GPIOC_BASE,8> blueLed;
typedef My_GPIO<GPIOA_BASE,0> button;

int main(void)
{
    //GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    volatile int dly;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN | RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN;

    blueLed::setMode(PINMODE_OUTPUT_2MHz);

    TIM3->PSC = 23999;           // Set prescaler to 24 000 (PSC + 1)
    TIM3->ARR = 1000;              // Auto reload value 1000
    TIM3->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE; // Enable update interrupt (timer level)
    TIM3->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;   // Enable timer

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn); // Enable interrupt from TIM3 (NVIC level)

    while (1) {
        for(dly = 0; dly < 500000; dly++)
            ;
        blueLed::setHigh();
    }
}

void TIM3_IRQHandler()
{
    ///irq flag cleared  -- the program was never here(checked)
}
```

Comment: Well, how do we know what files you are currently using? Publish them here or something (actual code, not only file names).

Comment: would it be okay? I think that there is problem with stack and place where irqhandlers are placed